# Loop over a column that has merged cells and add outside border

Tags: excel, vba

How to loop over merged cells in a given column? And then extend the range of that paticular merged cell to the right and add outside border in VBA?

I have the following table:

[image]

And expecting an output like this:

[image]

I have been trying the following:

```
Sub BrandsBorder()

    Dim Rng As Range, Dn As Range
    Set Rng = Range("B2", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    For Each Dn In Rng
        AddOutsideBorder Range(Dn, Dn.End(xlToRight))
    Next Dn

End Sub


Public Function AddOutsideBorders(rng As Range)
    With rng
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the property `MergeArea` of a cell to check if cells are merged together. `MergeArea` is a Range telling which cells belong to a merged area. For your cell "B2" ("Vans"), this would be "B2:B3". For single (unmerged) cells, `MergeArea` contains simply the address of cell cell itself (so for your cell "C2", this is "C2")

Now all you have to do while looping over your column B is to check if the cell is the *first* cell of the `MergeArea` and only then draw a frame, using that `MergeArea` as starting point for the border:

```
Sub BrandsBorder()

    With ActiveSheet  ' replace this with the worksheet you want to work with
        Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, borderRange As Range
        Set rng = .Range("B2", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

        For Each cell In rng
            ' Check if we are at the first cell of a merged area 
            If cell.MergeArea(1).Address = cell.Address Then
                Set borderRange = .Range(cell.MergeArea, cell.End(xlToRight))
                AddOutsideBorders borderRange
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```